# unable to load modules

Tags: haskell

I've just began using haskell.. I tried to run a sample script:

```
import Data.List
module main where

mylength = foldr (const (+1)) 0
main = print (mylength "haskell")
```

I get a simple error "modules loaded, none." I have zero idea why this is happening. 
I'm using GHCi under win7 32bit (if that matters). Am I missing something here?
the example doesn't even include the "module main where" but even without that it fails
to run.

Answer (score 3):

The `module` line always goes before `import`s. And the module name should start with a capital letter.

```
module Main where
import Data.List

mylength = foldr (const (+1)) 0
main = print (mylength "haskell")
```

If this doesn't work for you, please tell us

- the full error message you get; and
- which version of which compiler you're using

Comment: ohhh thanks, I did try that originally first but I had spaces before the mylength and main I guess that caused a problem too.

Comment: Yes, indentation is important in Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `module` line there.
When you do put it in, though, it must go *before* any import statements.

```
module main where  -- Optional, in the case of main.

import Data.List

myLength :: [a] -> Int
myLength = foldr (const (+1)) 0

main = print (mylength "haskell")
```